# Retrieve latest files from mediastore android

Tags: android, mediastore

As the question suggests i want to load recent files from mediastore.
By recent i mean files created or modified after a specific date or load latest 10-20 files.

what will be the query to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve files normally with the Cursor query depending on the files type you need.

After getting the file Itself (throgh URI) you can call the method `file.lastModified()` which returns long value.

```
Date lastModifedDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
```

Comment: That would be too memory and time expensive.There must be some way to do it by querying mediastore only